# Detect Directory Services Restore Mode in code

Tags: windows, active-directory

On a Windows domain controller, how can I verify from code that I am running in 'Directory Services Restore Mode'?

I need to do this from either Java, C or C++ but other code samples are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the Win API function [GetSystemMetrics(SM_CLEANBOOT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It gives an int result which can then be interpreted as follows:

- 0 = Running in Normal Mode
- 1 = Running in Safe Mode
- 2 = Running in Safe Mode with Networking
- 3 = Running in Directory Services Restore Mode

An alternative is to inspect the registry at:

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Option\OptionValue

When booting in Safe Mode, this registry key (which doesn't exist when booted normally) will contain a DWORD value that corresponds to the above values.

If the option value is 1 then only services and drivers specified under

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Minimal

will be loaded. Likewise if the value is 2 then only services and drivers specified under

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network

will be loaded